# List Files in all Subfolders in a Given Folder in Google Drive

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I'm trying to adapt a script found at https://github.com/bluexm/snipets/blob/master/list%20Gdrive%20files%20and%20folders.

While the creator of the script could assume unique folder names, I can't. So, I've made a couple of changes that should have resulted in limiting my search to the one folder. The problem is, this goes one level of subfolders, but not two. So, currently, the script searches 'Client Documents'/'2021-01-25'/'Subfolder1' and then stops, even though I need it to keep going to 'Client Documents'/'2021-01-25'/'Subfolder1'/'Sub-Subfolder2'.

Any thoughts on what has stopped this from going to Sub-Subfolder1?

```
function ListFilesandFolders(){
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  var fileno = sheet.getSheetName();
  var filenoFolders = DriveApp.searchFolders("title contains '"+fileno.replace("'","\'")+"' and trashed = false and hidden = false");
  var filenoFolder = filenoFolders.next().getFoldersByName("Internal Documents").next();
  var clientdocsFolders = filenoFolder.getFoldersByName("Disclosure").next().getFoldersByName("Our Client").next().getFolders();
  var clientdocsFolder = filenoFolder.getFoldersByName("Disclosure").next().getFoldersByName("Our Client").next();
  var aorFolder = clientdocsFolder.getFoldersByName("Affidavit of Records").next();
  var tz = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSpreadsheetTimeZone();
  var date = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), tz, "yyyy-MM-dd");
  
  // Find or Create doclist
  var aorFolderlist = aorFolder.getFiles();
  var doclist = "new"
  while (aorFolderlist.hasNext()) {
    var aorFile = aorFolderlist.next();
    if (aorFile.getName().includes("Document List")) {
      var doclist = SpreadsheetApp.open(aorFile);
      // doclist.duplicateActiveSheet().activate();
      // doclist.renameActiveSheet(date);
      // doclist.moveActiveSheet(0)
    }
  }
  if (doclist == "new") {
    var doclist = SpreadsheetApp.create(date + " Document List");
    doclist.renameActiveSheet(date);
    doclist.appendRow(["Document No.", "Document Date", "Document Title", "File Name", "URL", "Folder", "Date Created", "File ID", "File Name (No Date)", "Producible"]);
    DriveApp.getFileById(doclist.getId()).moveTo(aorFolder);
  }

  ListFilesandFolders1F(clientdocsFolders,'',doclist)
}

function ListFilesandFolders1F(fn,rfn,sheet) {
 
  // declare an array to push data into the spreadsheet
  var data = [];
  var count = 1;

  var foldersnext = fn.next();
  Logger.log("THE FOLDER IS "+foldersnext);// DEBUG

  // list files in this folder
  // myfiles is a File Iterator
  var myfiles = foldersnext.getFiles();

  Logger.log("FILES IN THIS FOLDER"); //DEBUG

  // loop through files in this folder
  while (myfiles.hasNext()) {
    var myfile = myfiles.next();
    count = Number(count) + 1;
    var shno = "#";
    var shdate = '=LEFT(D' + count + ',FIND(" ",D' + count + ')-1)';
    var shtitle = '=LEFT(I' + count + ',FIND(".",I' + count + ')-1)';
    var shfilename = '=RIGHT(D' + count + ',LEN(D' + count + ')-FIND(" ",D' + count + '))'; 
    var fname = myfile.getName();
    var fdate = myfile.getDateCreated();
    var fid = myfile.getId();
    var furl = myfile.getUrl();
    // Populate the array for this file
    data = [ 
      shno,
      shdate,
      shtitle,
      fname,
      furl,
      foldersnext,
      fdate,
      fid,
      shfilename
    ];
    //Logger.log("data = "+data); //DEBUG
    sheet.appendRow(data);
  } // Completes listing of the files in the named folder

  // Now get the subfolder
  // subfolders is a Folder Iterator
  var subfolders = foldersnext.getFolders();
  Logger.log("THE SUBFOLDER(S) ARE"); //DEBUG HEADING

  // now start a loop on the SubFolder list
  while (subfolders.hasNext()) {
    var subfolderdata = [];
    var mysubfolders = subfolders.next().getFolders();
    var mysubfolder = mysubfolders.next();  
    
    ListFilesandFolders1F(mysubfolders,rfn +'/'+ mysubfolder,sheet)
  
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

And here's the answer:

```
/* Adapted from Code written by @hubgit https://gist.github.com/hubgit/3755293
Updated since DocsList is deprecated  https://ctrlq.org/code/19854-list-files-in-google-drive-folder

Bluexm: added recursion on subfolders */

// List all files and sub-folders in a folder and subfolders Google Drive

// entry function 
function ListFilesandFolders(){
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  var fileno = sheet.getSheetName();
  var filenoFolders = DriveApp.searchFolders("title contains '"+fileno.replace("'","\'")+"' and trashed = false and hidden = false");
  var filenoFolder = filenoFolders.next().getFoldersByName("Internal Documents").next();
  var clientdocsFolder = filenoFolder.getFoldersByName("Disclosure").next().getFoldersByName("Our Client").next();
  var aorFolder = clientdocsFolder.getFoldersByName("Affidavit of Records").next();
  var tz = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSpreadsheetTimeZone();
  var date = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), tz, "yyyy-MM-dd");
  
  // Find or Create doclist
  var aorFolderlist = aorFolder.getFiles();
  var doclist = "new"
  while (aorFolderlist.hasNext()) {
    var aorFile = aorFolderlist.next();
    if (aorFile.getName().includes("Document List")) {
      var doclist = SpreadsheetApp.open(aorFile);
      // doclist.duplicateActiveSheet().activate();
      // doclist.renameActiveSheet(date);
      // doclist.moveActiveSheet(0)
    }
  }
  if (doclist == "new") {
    var doclist = SpreadsheetApp.create(date + " Document List");
    doclist.renameActiveSheet(date);
    doclist.appendRow(["Document No.", "Document Date", "Document Title", "File Name", "URL", "Folder", "Date Created", "File ID", "File Name (No Date)", "Producible"]);
    DriveApp.getFileById(doclist.getId()).moveTo(aorFolder);
  }

  ListFilesandFolders1F(clientdocsFolder,'',doclist)
}

function ListFilesandFolders1F(fn,rfn,sheet) {
 
  // declare an array to push data into the spreadsheet
  var data = [];
  var count = 1;

  var foldersnext = fn;
  Logger.log("THE FOLDER IS "+foldersnext);// DEBUG

  // list files in this folder
  // myfiles is a File Iterator
  var myfiles = foldersnext.getFiles();

  Logger.log("FILES IN THIS FOLDER"); //DEBUG

  // loop through files in this folder
  while (myfiles.hasNext()) {
    var myfile = myfiles.next();
    count = Number(count) + 1;
    var shno = "#";
    var shdate = '=LEFT(D' + count + ',FIND(" ",D' + count + ')-1)';
    var shtitle = '=LEFT(I' + count + ',FIND(".",I' + count + ')-1)';
    var shfilename = '=RIGHT(D' + count + ',LEN(D' + count + ')-FIND(" ",D' + count + '))'; 
    var fname = myfile.getName();
    var fdate = myfile.getDateCreated();
    var fid = myfile.getId();
    var furl = myfile.getUrl();
    // Populate the array for this file
    data = [ 
      shno,
      shdate,
      shtitle,
      fname,
      furl,
      foldersnext.getName(),
      fdate,
      fid,
      shfilename
    ];
    //Logger.log("data = "+data); //DEBUG
    sheet.appendRow(data);
  } // Completes listing of the files in the named folder

  // Now get the subfolder
  // subfolders is a Folder Iterator
  var subfolders = foldersnext.getFolders();
  Logger.log("THE SUBFOLDER(S) ARE"); //DEBUG HEADING

  // now start a loop on the SubFolder list
  while (subfolders.hasNext()) {
    var subfolderdata = [];
    var mysubfolders = subfolders.next(); 

    ListFilesandFolders1F(mysubfolders,rfn +'/'+ fn,sheet)
  
  }
}
```